# builder install --without rmagick failed in openproject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, rubygems, openproject

I got openproject running in windows after a long struggle since new to ruby world. I cannot suggest to my colleagues until install this openproject in Oracle Linux (part of RHEL).

Checked out openproject from Git successfully using following cmd

```
git clone https://github.com/opf/openproject.git
cd openproject
git checkout stable
```

next When i run `builder install --without rmagick` getting following error,

```
...
....
.....
Using addressable 2.3.4
Using awesome_nested_set 2.1.6
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141018-4810-1x3qn6f-0.rb extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I.   -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fno-strict-aliasing  -fPIC  -O0 -std=c99  -c binding_of_caller.c
binding_of_caller.c:4:21: error: vm_core.h: No such file or directory
binding_of_caller.c:5:22: error: rubys_gc.h: No such file or directory
binding_of_caller.c:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
binding_of_caller.c: In function ‘binding_memsize’:
binding_of_caller.c:34: error: ‘rb_binding_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:34: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
binding_of_caller.c:34: error: for each function it appears in.)
binding_of_caller.c: In function ‘binding_free’:
binding_of_caller.c:40: error: ‘rb_binding_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:40: error: ‘bind’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:41: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘RUBY_FREE_ENTER’
binding_of_caller.c:46: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘RUBY_FREE_LEAVE’
binding_of_caller.c: In function ‘binding_mark’:
binding_of_caller.c:52: error: ‘rb_binding_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:52: error: ‘bind’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:53: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘RUBY_MARK_ENTER’
binding_of_caller.c:56: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘RUBY_MARK_UNLESS_NULL’
binding_of_caller.c:63: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘RUBY_MARK_LEAVE’
binding_of_caller.c: At top level:
binding_of_caller.c:66: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘binding_data_type’
binding_of_caller.c: In function ‘binding_alloc’:
binding_of_caller.c:77: error: ‘rb_binding_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:77: error: ‘bind’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:78: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘TypedData_Make_Struct’
binding_of_caller.c:78: error: ‘binding_data_type’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c: At top level:
binding_of_caller.c:82: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
binding_of_caller.c:86: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
binding_of_caller.c:90: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
binding_of_caller.c: In function ‘frametype_name’:
binding_of_caller.c:108: error: ‘VM_FRAME_MAGIC_MASK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:109: error: ‘VM_FRAME_MAGIC_METHOD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:110: error: ‘VM_FRAME_MAGIC_BLOCK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:111: error: ‘VM_FRAME_MAGIC_CLASS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:112: error: ‘VM_FRAME_MAGIC_TOP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:113: error: ‘VM_FRAME_MAGIC_CFUNC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:114: error: ‘VM_FRAME_MAGIC_PROC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:115: error: ‘VM_FRAME_MAGIC_IFUNC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:116: error: ‘VM_FRAME_MAGIC_EVAL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:117: error: ‘VM_FRAME_MAGIC_LAMBDA’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c: In function ‘binding_of_caller’:
binding_of_caller.c:125: error: ‘rb_thread_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:125: error: ‘th’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:126: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘GetThreadPtr’
binding_of_caller.c:128: error: ‘rb_control_frame_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:128: error: ‘cfp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:128: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘RUBY_VM_PREVIOUS_CONTROL_FRAME’
binding_of_caller.c:129: error: ‘limit_cfp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:140: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘valid_frame_p’
binding_of_caller.c:141: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘find_valid_frame’
binding_of_caller.c:145: error: ‘rb_binding_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:145: error: ‘bind’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:150: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘GetBindingPtr’
binding_of_caller.c:152: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rb_vm_make_env_object’
binding_of_caller.c:154: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rb_vm_get_sourceline’
binding_of_caller.c: In function ‘frame_count’:
binding_of_caller.c:176: error: ‘rb_thread_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:176: error: ‘th’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:179: error: ‘rb_control_frame_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:179: error: ‘cfp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
binding_of_caller.c:180: error: ‘limit_cfp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [binding_of_caller.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/binding_of_caller-0.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.8/binding_of_caller-0.7.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing binding_of_caller (0.7.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install binding_of_caller -v '0.7.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

i cannot understand whether this error related to any dependency problem or am i checked out an wrong version.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a ruby version (1.8) not supported by [binding_of_caller](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller#binding_of_caller) and also not supported by [OpenProject](https://community.openproject.org/projects/openproject/wiki/systemrequirements) . You will need to install ruby 2.1.

If possible on Oracle Linux, I would recommend doing this via [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installation).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this in the [installation guide on Ubuntu](https://community.openproject.org/projects/openproject/wiki/Installation_Ubuntu), but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16790034/6309) recommends:

> You need to [install ruby-debug](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-debug) first passing the include directory.

```
gem install ruby-debug -- --with-ruby-include=$rvm_path/src/ruby-1.9.3-p362
```

(adapt it to your ruby version)